# How to switch between Apple Silicon M1 bases PHP version(php@7.4) with (Rosetta 2) based PHP version(php@7.3)

Tags: php, apple-m1, apple-silicon, rosetta

I have installed php@7.3 using rosetta 2 on the Apple Silicon M1 Big Sur macbook. And also I have natively installed php@7.4 as well. I have a project which needs to use php@7.3 version. But when I `php -v` it outputs the php@7.4 version. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What prompted your assumption on requiring an older version? And why doesn't fixing the PATH or webserver setup suffice? Why do you think the compilation/machine targets are relevant?

Comment: My project needs to use php7.3 version. Previously I had Intel based Mac. But It got crashed. I cannot update it to php 7.4 yet. That's why I need to use the rosetta installed php7.3. Do you know how to do it ? @mario

Comment: Why would the project need 7.3? How did you test this? Or is it just a requirements list and the usual understanding woes about the significance of minor versions?

Comment: Previously I tested it with my intel based Mac.Now I got the M1 based Mac. It's a project requirement. I need to know can I use the rosetta installed php version instead of native php7.4 version to test the application. I'm using php web storm ide.